# FlexSlider doesn't load Query?

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I did everything right, Imported all images\js\css of the slider, posted the HTML, linked the images and thats what it is showing me:

http://gyazo.com/d893652fb91023d1ebd5278383ae72e6.png

I don't know whats wrong?

www.justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html

My HTML:

http://pastebin.com/FEK7AHBr

Flex CSS:

http:// pastebin.com/ YSNQXQ53

thanks

Comment: In your html mark up your are referencing "Flexslider" js twice. One is min version and other is normal descriptive.

Comment: I've tried removing one of the links, and nothing worked.

Comment: Prepare a fiddle in jsfiddle so we can find where the actual issue is?

Comment: What do you mean by Jsfiddle? whats inside the js files?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), its basically an online tool where you can prepare your demo and anybody can access that via its URL.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9eZjb/1/ there, images are not working but its okay I guess..

Comment: just make the demo you have just copied html and css, put the js code in right container and reference the js file correctly. [Here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net) is documentation to use jsfiddle

Comment: Well I did link the JS everything in connected but images

Comment: I've tried another slider, and it's also not working.. not calling the query I dont know whats going on..

Comment: I've figured out what was the problem, it was my framework. it wanted the js files to be in the /js/ folder, otherwise it would ignore it.

But still im getting errors:

http://justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html

When sliding can u see there's some part of the previous slide image on the left side? why it does that?

Comment: Also one more problem, as you see when you hover the categories menu, the items goes behind the slider?